# What are the last five digits of $1+11+111+\cdots+\underbrace{11111...1}_{\text{$2002$ "1"s}}$?

Tags: contest-math

Question 25 of the Australian Mathematics Competition, Junior Level, Year 2002:

> What are the last 5 digits of this sum?
> $$1+11+111+\cdots+\underbrace{11111...1}_{\text{$2002$ "1"s}}$$ Note, the last number a.k.a $11111...$ contains 2002 digits of 1.

I've tried to solve this problem but could only get through half of the question.

My method:

So firstly, let's try to solve for the last digit. The one digit can be obtained by adding all 2002 1's together. This ends with a 2. Thus the last digit is 2. Using the same logic for the second to last and 3rd to last digits, they should be 1 and 0 respectively. This means that the answer should end in XX012. I was correct so far but got stuck on the next few steps.

You help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Hint: $1\ldots 1 = (10^n-1)/9$.  Do you know the sum of a geometric progression?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How would one go about finding the last four digits of this sum?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4693105/how-would-one-go-about-finding-the-last-four-digits-of-this-sum)

Comment: FYI, using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%241%2B11%2B111%2B%5Cldots%2B%5Cunderbrace%7B11111...1%7D_%7B%5Ctext%7B2002%20%27%271%27%27s%7D%7D%24%2C%20OR%20content%3Alast%2C%20OR%20content%3Adigits&p=1), there's the related question of [Sum of series : $1+11+111+...$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1946906).

Comment: Just continue what you were doing:  you want $ ...80000 +  ..99000     +      .00000    +      20010     +        2002$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define $n_i$ in the obvious manner.  Then for $i \geq 5, n_i \equiv 11111 \pmod{100000}$.  Thus, you're looking for:

\begin{align}\sum_{i=1}^{2002} n_i \pmod {100000} &\equiv 1234 + \sum_{i=5}^{2002} 11111 \pmod {100000} \\
&\equiv 1234 + 1998 \cdot 11111 \pmod {100000} \\
&\equiv 1234 + 99778 \pmod {100000} \\
& \equiv 1012 \pmod {100000}.\end{align}

The last five digits of the sum, therefore, are $01012$.

Comment: Very nice proof.